# What are the steps to getting this 'custom' permalink scheme in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, permalinks

I'm writing a Jekyll setup and I'd like to get my posts to have a permalink in the form: `/2013/jan/something-something-in-january`. I understand that it is impossible with vanilla permalinks to:

- get the `:month` to be in text form **or**
- get the `:title` to be dash delimited

I remember reading somewhere that I could achieve this by writing a plugin, but I'm not sure how. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you ask how you can write a plugin for jekyll in general, or do you need assistance with a specific step in the plugin development?

Comment: @Polygnome I'd like some help writing the plugin to accomplish this (the latter).

Comment: That question is way too broad to answer. What is the **specific** problem you are facing?

Comment: I'd like to get my posts to have a permalink in the form: `/2013/jan/something-something-in-january`. 

I can't do this with the vanilla permalink implementation. What are the steps to creating a plugin that would do this (i.e. what classes to extend etc.)

Comment: Yes i understood that. But the question is: What prevents you from doing so? What specific problem do you face? If you don't know how to write a jekyll plugin in general, look at the jekyll wiki, it is explained there. Otherwise, at which step do you get stuck? SO is not a site where you post your problem and someone posts the source code for your plugin as solution - come up with good, specific questions, and we'll be able to help.

Comment: Ok, so it is not immediately obvious for me how I could accomplish this. There are 4 categories of plugins - Generators, Converters, Tags and Filters. What I want doesn't fall into any of these. After having a look now, I think I know what I should modify - [permalink](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/post.rb#L179) method of Post. What I am unsure about is how to 'hook' this method - **I need to override the permalink method only for posts in the category 'post'**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a generator plugin:

```
module Jekyll
    class PermalinkRewriter < Generator
        safe true
        priority :low

        def generate(site)
            # Until Jekyll allows me to use :slug, I have to resort to this
            site.posts.each do |item|
                item.data['permalink'] = '/' + item.slug + '/'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @liamzebedee! This is a great starting point for those of us trying to do something with the permalinks.

Comment: @PerLundberg this is also another great starting point: https://github.com/search?q=class+PermalinkRewriter+%3C+Generator&ref=reposearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93