# Jekyll: mod category and tag permalinks in Ruby

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have a custom plugin adapted from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17206081/1412255) which I'm using to customise post permalinks for a multi-language website on Jekyll.

```rb
module Jekyll
    class PermalinkRewriter < Generator
        safe true
        priority :low

        def generate(site)
            site.posts.docs.each do |item|
                item.data['permalink'] = '/' + item.lang + '/blog/' + item.slug
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible for similar implementations for category and tag pages, with the language for each category/tag set based on whether at least one post exists in each (then using the first post's language to set it). Maybe this can be achieved with `front matter do`?

Comment: Which plugin (if any) are you using to generate those category/tag pages?

Comment: @Ross jekyll-category-pages and jekyll-tagging.